# MicrosoftMvcAjax breaks jQuery validate plugin

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax, jquery-validate

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jquery validate & ajax.beginform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1163537/jquery-validate-ajax-beginform)

I'm trying to use the jQuery validate plugin to validate a form (Ajax.BeginForm). When I enter invalid data on the form the error messages are shown but the form will submit anyway.
How do I stop MicrosoftMvcAjax from submiting an invalid form?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Appears to be duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1163537/jquery-validate-ajax-beginform

Comment: Yes, it was a duplicate. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I got it!

All I need to do is pass the validate function to the OnBegin event in the AjaxOptions:

```
<% using (Ajax.BeginForm("SendMail", "Mail", new { @id = "MailForm", @class = "cmxform" }, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "dialog", OnBegin = "validate" }, new { @id = "MailForm" }))
       { %>
```