# ASP.NET MVC Ajax form and jQuery validation

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-validate

I have the same scenario as this question, but with a different problem:

[ASP.Net MVC Ajax form with jQuery validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298691/asp-net-mvc-ajax-form-with-jquery-validation)

I've set the `AjaxOptions.OnBegin` property to call `return $('form').validate().form();` which works fine for when validation fails; the validation messages are displayed and the form is not posted. However, since setting `AjaxOptions.OnBegin`, I now get a full page refresh rather than an Ajax call when there are no validation errors. It only happens if `AjaxOptions.OnBegin` is set. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've fixed my problem. I was setting the value of OnBegin to `return $("#form").validate().form()` which was never going to work because it's expecting a function name, so I created a function:

```
function validateForm(){
   return $("#form").validate().form();
}
```

and set the OnBegin property to `validateForm`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe when `AjaxOptions.OnBegin` returns true, it exits the Ajax call.

Try setting `AjaxOptions.OnBegin` to something like

```
if(!$('form').validate().form()) {
  return false;
}
```

Only return false.  If its valid, it just continues.