# Mvc3 validatios are not firing

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am using Javascript serializer for passing model data to controller but this is not            firing the code validation.
Here is the code

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/microsoftajax.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/MicrosoftMvcAjax.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

 $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#btnCreateDepartment").click(function () {

            var name = $('#txtDeptName').val();
            $.ajax({
                data: { modelName: 'DEPARTMENT', values: Sys.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.serialize(
                {
                    DeptName: name
                }
            )
                },
                url: '@Url.Action("Create", "Office")',
                type: "POST",
                complete: function (result) {
                    debugger
                    alert("complete");
                },
                error: function (result) {
                    debugger
                    alert(result.statusText);
                }
            }); //Endof ajax
            return false;
        }); //end of click

    });    // end of ready
</script>
```

In model the i have added validation as following

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Please Enter department")]
        public string DeptName { get; set; }
```

But this is not getting fired .

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5200098/asp-net-mvc-3-ajax-form-submit-and-validation . hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Passing the object via ajax to the controller will disable the default mvc validation form. This validation will only work if you do a normal post. 
Anyway if you want to use ajax you need to do the validation using jquery. If you decide not to use ajax then you can use mvc's built in validation. I also recommend fluent validation library for MVC

Comment: Thanks teahupoo i tried using validations using jquery by adding foll owing code to my view $.validator.addMethod("validateEvent",
  function () {
      alert("validating");
  }) but this is not working

Answer (score 0):

Change data parameter of your jQuery ajax to

```
data: { DeptName: name },
```

so it contains only properties of your model. Other department properties should follow DeptName ex. `{ DeptName: name, DeptAddress: address, ... }`.

If your mvc model was mirrored on client side as a javascript model `department` you would just go:

```
data: { JSON.stringify(department) },
```