# Client Side Validation on date picked to show a textbox in asp.net

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, asp.net-mvc, validation

I'm trying to add validation to a date textbox, where if the current date picked is less than present date, a textbox appears for additional information.

I've been able to add a custom validation to it, but it only works on hitting the submit button, I'd like to know if there is a way where we can validate the date when picked to show the textbox in a dynamic way rather then hitting the submit button for the textbox to be generated.

Comment: Use ajax validation. This question might help 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5200098/asp-net-mvc-3-ajax-form-submit-and-validation

Comment: thanks, seems a bit to confusing, as my ajax knowledge is a little less, but I shall have a look into it.

Answer (score 0):

you can write script for this

```
$(function () {
    $('#textboxid').datepicker({ minDate: +0 });
});
```